# How to animate Rotation of a PNG image in VSE?

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor

I selected the Transform effect green rectangle, then I moved to frame #10, and lastly, I changed the Rotation value. Shouldn't a Keyframe have been made at that moment?
I am starting to suspect that of all things animatable, this is not one of them, is it?
[image]

Comment: One keyframe isn't enough, you need at least two different ones that can be interpolated in between. So add one without rotation at frame one as well and you should be good to go. Oh and a keyframe has to be inserted with the I hotkey or via context menu... Alternatively you can switch auto keyframing on. But that might have side effects you don't want. Search for a simple animation tutorial for blender to grasp the idea of how to animate values. Or watch the excellent YouTube tutorials from Mikeycal Meyers about the VSE. He should be mentioning animating values in there.

Answer (score 1):

It's animatable, but it isn't automatic. Move the mouse cursor above the Rotation slider, and hit <kbd>i</kbd> when you want to add a keyframe.